# unknown packaging nar - nar-maven-plugin

Tags: c++, c, maven, plugins, packaging

I use Maven to manage my Java projects build but sometimes I have projects written in C or C++ langage and I would like to use Maven too so it will be easier to manage those projects.

It seems the `nar-maven-plugin` should do the job. I tried to create an HelloWorld project just to test it. I thought it will be really simple as it is generally with Maven.

My pom.xml

```xml
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworld-cplusplus-sample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>nar</packaging>
  <name>Helloworld</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
        <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <libraries>
                <library>
                    <type>executable</type>
                </library>
            </libraries>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And i have the following error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: nar @ line 7, column 14
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.sample:helloworld-cplusplus-sample:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (D:\local\workspaces\TEST\HelloWorl
dMaven\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: nar @ line 7, column 14
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

I'm using Maven 3.3.1.

I forced the download of nar-maven-plugin in my local repository using "mvn dependency:get ..." but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't understand: the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34089610/1743880) by user3282942 does not resolve the `Unknown packaging: nar`error. Why did you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already answered, ;)

> link.exe is part of Microsoft Visual Studio, which is what NAR
>   typically uses under the hood to compile C++ code on Windows.

Try with

```
<linker> 
<name>g++</name>
</linker>
```

in your nar plugin configuration if you have MinGW or something other than MSVS.

Answer (score 2):

When a plugin adds a new packaging type, you must add `<extensions>true</extensions>` to its definition:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
    <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions> <!-- This needs to be present for a new packaging -->
    <configuration>
        <libraries>
            <library>
                <type>executable</type>
            </library>
        </libraries>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```